# PDF file open new tab

Tags: 7, entities, javascript, files

I'm using Drupal 7. My theme Omega. And have got file field in my site. Uploaded all pdf files and everything working.

But, when i click pdf files on Firefox, my pdf file starting download. When i click on Chrome, pdf open in same page.

Checked by Firebug, pdf file html code is here:

```
<span class="file"><img src="/modules/file/icons/application-pdf.png" title="application/pdf" alt="" class="file-icon"> <a title="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=1620377" href="http://mysite.net/sites/default/files/myfile.pdf">Click to Download</a></span>
```

I want when click pdf file, open a new tab, so make attribute. Drupal file module is (file.js):

```
 *
 * This file provides progress bar support (if available), popup windows for
 * file previews, and disabling of other file fields during Ajax uploads (which
 * prevents separate file fields from accidentally uploading files).
 */

(function ($) {

/**
 * Attach behaviors to managed file element upload fields.
 */
Drupal.behaviors.fileValidateAutoAttach = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    if (settings.file && settings.file.elements) {
      $.each(settings.file.elements, function(selector) {
        var extensions = settings.file.elements[selector];
        $(selector, context).bind('change', {extensions: extensions}, Drupal.file.validateExtension);
      });
    }
  },
  detach: function (context, settings) {
    if (settings.file && settings.file.elements) {
      $.each(settings.file.elements, function(selector) {
        $(selector, context).unbind('change', Drupal.file.validateExtension);
      });
    }
  }
};

/**
 * Attach behaviors to the file upload and remove buttons.
 */
Drupal.behaviors.fileButtons = {
  attach: function (context) {
    $('input.form-submit', context).bind('mousedown', Drupal.file.disableFields);
    $('div.form-managed-file input.form-submit', context).bind('mousedown', Drupal.file.progressBar);
  },
  detach: function (context) {
    $('input.form-submit', context).unbind('mousedown', Drupal.file.disableFields);
    $('div.form-managed-file input.form-submit', context).unbind('mousedown', Drupal.file.progressBar);
  }
};

/**
 * Attach behaviors to links within managed file elements.
 */
Drupal.behaviors.filePreviewLinks = {
  attach: function (context) {
    $('div.form-managed-file .file a, .file-widget .file a', context).bind('click',Drupal.file.openInNewWindow);
  },
  detach: function (context){
    $('div.form-managed-file .file a, .file-widget .file a', context).unbind('click', Drupal.file.openInNewWindow);
  }
};

/**
 * File upload utility functions.
 */
Drupal.file = Drupal.file || {
  /**
   * Client-side file input validation of file extensions.
   */
  validateExtension: function (event) {
    // Remove any previous errors.
    $('.file-upload-js-error').remove();

    // Add client side validation for the input[type=file].
    var extensionPattern = event.data.extensions.replace(/,\s*/g, '|');
    if (extensionPattern.length > 1 && this.value.length > 0) {
      var acceptableMatch = new RegExp('\\.(' + extensionPattern + ')$', 'gi');
      if (!acceptableMatch.test(this.value)) {
        var error = Drupal.t("The selected file %filename cannot be uploaded. Only files with the following extensions are allowed: %extensions.", {
          '%filename': this.value,
          '%extensions': extensionPattern.replace(/\|/g, ', ')
        });
        $(this).parents('div.form-managed-file').prepend('<div class="messages error file-upload-js-error">' + error + '</div>');
        this.value = '';
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  /**
   * Prevent file uploads when using buttons not intended to upload.
   */
  disableFields: function (event){
    var clickedButton = this;

    // Only disable upload fields for Ajax buttons.
    if (!$(clickedButton).hasClass('ajax-processed')) {
      return;
    }

    // Check if we're working with an "Upload" button.
    var $enabledFields = [];
    if ($(this).parents('div.form-managed-file').size() > 0) {
      $enabledFields = $(this).parents('div.form-managed-file').find('input.form-file');
    }

    // Temporarily disable upload fields other than the one we're currently
    // working with. Filter out fields that are already disabled so that they
    // do not get enabled when we re-enable these fields at the end of behavior
    // processing. Re-enable in a setTimeout set to a relatively short amount
    // of time (1 second). All the other mousedown handlers (like Drupal's Ajax
    // behaviors) are excuted before any timeout functions are called, so we
    // don't have to worry about the fields being re-enabled too soon.
    // @todo If the previous sentence is true, why not set the timeout to 0?
    var $fieldsToTemporarilyDisable = $('div.form-managed-file input.form-file').not($enabledFields).not(':disabled');
    $fieldsToTemporarilyDisable.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function (){
      $fieldsToTemporarilyDisable.attr('disabled', '');
    }, 1000);
  },
  /**
   * Add progress bar support if possible.
   */
  progressBar: function (event) {
    var clickedButton = this;
    var $progressId = $(clickedButton).parents('div.form-managed-file').find('input.file-progress');
    if ($progressId.size()) {
      var originalName = $progressId.attr('name');

      // Replace the name with the required identifier.
      $progressId.attr('name', originalName.match(/APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS|UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER/)[0]);

      // Restore the original name after the upload begins.
      setTimeout(function () {
        $progressId.attr('name', originalName);
      }, 1000);
    }
    // Show the progress bar if the upload takes longer than half a second.
    setTimeout(function () {
      $(clickedButton).parents('div.form-managed-file').find('div.ajax-progress-bar').slideDown();
    }, 500);
  },
  /**
   * Open links to files within forms in a new window.
   */
  openInNewWindow: function (event) {
    $(this).attr('target', '_new');
    window.open(this.href, 'filePreview', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=1,statusbar=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=500,height=550');
    return false;
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

I don't have page.tpl files, so must this jQuery or another way. How can i do this?

Comment: Isn't the difference between opening in a new tab just the difference between Firefox and Chrome?  One opens in a new tab by default and the other downloads.

Comment: Also, is this a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29346/click-to-file-blank-page?  If yes, you should edit your old question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: @PatrickKenny deleted another question. Yes, i want all opens new tab by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patrick is right that this is more of a issue with how different browsers (and the users' individual settings) than anything with your template. That said there is some research support ([useit.com](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/open_new_windows.html)) for at least trying to implement this functionality for users but its probably outside the scope of Drupal so if you want this, you're going to need to update your theme to rewrite these links to add a jquery override for PDF files, like this one:

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/dom-scripting/pdf-new-window.shtml

Answer (score -1):

In case anybody else have the same problem, I recommend the External Links module. To use this module for PDF files, just type .*.pdf in the matching pattern field, being careful of typing the complete regular expression, to avoid conflicts with the javascript.
For some screenshots of the process, follow: http://www.inqbation.com/open-pdf-files-in-new-tab/ ... It is pretty simple.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.